# bundle: command not found - in bash script, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, bundle, gemfile

The "bundle install" command fails in a bash script
prints "bundle: command not found"
but if I start manually then everything works, what could be the problem?
script body:
cd reddit (- here's the Gemfile file) && bundle install

Comment: I think bundle (I don't know what it is) is not set in the $PATH of your script environment. instead of "bundle install", use the absolute path: for example: "/usr/bin/bundle install". (running "which bundle" in shell will give you the path) .

Comment: thank you friend you helped, I suffered for a week